# What is wrong is the puppeteer script that stops it saving the scraped data to a file?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

What is wrong here? I need to be able to scrape the data CSS selectors from the URLs in the const URLs array, and then save that information back into a file in an array. I've been playing with getting this working for ages, but I think I don't understand something correctly and thus am missing something, any pointers please?

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const colors = require('colors/safe');
const fs = require('fs');
const bluebird = require("bluebird");
const https = require('https');
const querystring = require('querystring');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Now you can go wherever you want
  const urls = ['/news/england/', '/news/wales/']
  const results = await bluebird.map(urls, async(url) => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0')
    await page.goto('https://www.bbc.com' + url);
    await page.setViewport({
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
      deviceScaleFactor: 1,
    });
    await sleep(60000);
    await page.waitForSelector('#topos-component');
    const [a, b] = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const a = document.querySelector("a.gel-paragon-bold");
      const aText = a.innerText;
      const b = document.querySelectorAll(".gs-o-responsive-image--lead > img:nth-child(1)");
      const bText = b.href;
      return [aText, bText];
    }, {
      concurrency: 3
    })
  });

  fs.writeFileSync('test.html', JSON.stringify(results));

  // Then when you're done, just close
  await browser.close();

  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: What's the problematic behavior exactly? Why use Bluebeard when Node has native promises now? Puppeteer also has `waitForTimeout` so you don't need to write `sleep` (and it's poor practice to use either). I don't see that you're returning anything from your `map` call. Also, I don't see full URLs here so the code can't be executed by folks trying to help.

Comment: it does execute and pulls back the URL its just not getting the CSS element, I am using the bluebeard and sleep as that is what was working for me, if you have a better idea I'm happy to see it.

Comment: the sleep function is there because the pages I am scraping take about 30 seconds to load due to a anti ddos check

Comment: `page.waitForTimeout(60000)` is the Puppeteer method. But better to `waitForFunction(predicate that checks for the page loaded)` or `page.waitForSelector(some selector that appears after the page is loaded)`. The problem is, 60 seconds might be too long (wastes time) or too short (fails). See [Antipatterns: overusing `waitForTimeout`](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#overusing-waitfortimeout)

Comment: Better idea than bringing in Bluebeard, an unnecessary and outdated/legacy third-party dep: `Promise.all`. Glad you see you worked it out and are returning results from the mapper, though.

Comment: If you have examples happy to have a look

Comment: Replace `bluebird.map` with [`Promise.all(urls.map(async url => ...))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: yeah that promise.all works fine, thanks. now the next task is dealing with if the query selector is empty or doesn't exist to contune and show 'n/a' instead of the const

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it and got it working how I need it

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const colors = require('colors/safe');
const fs = require('fs');
const bluebird = require("bluebird");
const https = require('https');
const querystring = require('querystring');


(async () => {
    const args = ['--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'];
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://check.torproject.org/');
    const isUsingTor = await page.$eval('body', el =>
        el.innerHTML.includes('Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor')
    );

    if (!isUsingTor) {
        console.log(colors.red.bold('Not using Tor. Closing...'));
        return await browser.close();
    }

    console.log(colors.green.bold('Using Tor. Continuing... '));

    // Now you can go wherever you want
    
    const urls = ['/xxxx123','/xxxxxx345','/xxxxxx567']
    const results = await bluebird.map(urls, async (url) => {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
        await page.setUserAgent('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
        await page.goto('https://aaaaaaaa.com'+url);
        await page.setViewport({
            width: 1920,
            height: 1080,
            deviceScaleFactor: 1,
        });
        await sleep(60000);
        await page.waitForSelector('.xxxx', { timeout: 30000 });
        const xx1 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.xx1').innerText);
        const xx2= await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.xx2').innerText);
        const xx3 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('xx3').innerText);
        const publish_date = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.post-banner-p').innerText);
        const xx4= await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.xx4').innerText);
        const xx5= await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.xx5').innerText);
        const xx6 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('xx6)').innerText);
        const xx7 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('xx7').innerText);
        const xx8 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.xx8').innerText);
        const xx9 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.xx9').innerText);

        return [xx1,xx2,xx3,xx4,xx5,xx6,xx7,xx8,xx9];
        }, {
        concurrency: 3
    });
    fs.writeFileSync('xxxxxxx.html', JSON.stringify(results));

    // Then when you're done, just close
    await browser.close();

    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, ms);

        });

    }

})();
```